# JavaScript library to load resources on-demand?

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

Is there a library that allows to load scripts and stylesheets dynamically on demand with callback support?

All I could find is an incomplete snippets of code here and there and library called [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) which is deprecated without a good reason.

Comment: there are hundreds, keep looking.

Comment: Use the system module loader shim. SystemJS. Or just something like webpack.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Jquery's getScript method

$.getScript('the path of the script you want to load',successCallback)

Comment: Sadly, jQuery's method is unreliable when external script is loaded from different domain name, it will not fire a callback. Will have to look for another solution.

Comment: how about using jsonp, that should work for cross-domain requests